# Google Cloud Storage with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I tried a lot to configure my laravel project with google cloud storage system.

This is my filesystem.php :

```
'gcs' => [
  'driver' => 'gcs',
  'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'mamachrili-200220'),
  'key_file' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', app_path('key.json')), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
  'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'mamachrilipictures'),
  'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', null), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
  'storage_api_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
],
```

and this my .env file

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID='my project id'
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET='my bucket'
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX=
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI=
```

now the problem is :

when I try to put or copy or do anything exepct get the url :

I get this error :

> { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid JWT
>   Signature." }

NB : I've given all permissions to AllUser on the google cloud console.

Comment: Can you show us how you manage authentication in your code? How do handle the JWT?

Comment: Are you running this code on Google App Engine or Compute Engine? What is `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE` set to? If set, is the file/path valid? Post your code that shows how you are setting up and using credentials.